# Delay in drawing on windows 7 OS

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-7

I need to identify some wnds in my application (objects of CMDIChildWnd class).
To do this i am using a timer to draw the border of the wnd with specific color alternatively so as to give the feel of blinking. This works perfectly fine on WinXP machines, but faires miserably on Win7 machines; there is significant delay in painting the highlighted border.
However when switched to *optimize for best performance* setting everything works just smooth.

I am using `CCLinetDC::Rectangle()` method to draw the border. Is there some known issue with this API in Win7? How can I make it work on Win7 as well?

Comment: What's being switched to "optimize for best performance?" Is that a compiler option or an OS setting or?

Comment: Its the OS setting David. Precisely under _Adjust Visual Effects_ setting from the control pannel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with disabling NC area painting.

Something like below:

```
#include <dwmapi.h>
...

HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
if (IsVistaOrAbove())
{
    DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY ncrp = DWMNCRP_DISABLED;
    hr = ::DwmSetWindowAttribute(m_hWnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &ncrp, sizeof(ncrp));
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
}
```

But it also disables Aero on the window.

So it would be more straightforward to show blink in the client area not in the border.

**UPDATED**

For XP compatibility, you should use DWM APIs like this:

```
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *pfnDwmIsCompositionEnabled)(BOOL *pfEnabled);
static pfnDwmIsCompositionEnabled s_DwmIsCompositionEnabled;
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *pfnDwmSetWindowAttribute)(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute);
static pfnDwmSetWindowAttribute s_DwmSetWindowAttribute;
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *pfnDwmGetWindowAttribute)(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute);
static pfnDwmGetWindowAttribute s_DwmGetWindowAttribute;


HMODULE hSysDll = LoadLibrary(_T("dwmapi.dll"));
if(hSysDll) // Loaded dwmapi.dll success, must Vista or above
{
    s_DwmIsCompositionEnabled = (pfnDwmIsCompositionEnabled)GetProcAddress(hSysDll, "DwmIsCompositionEnabled");
    s_DwmSetWindowAttribute = (pfnDwmSetWindowAttribute)GetProcAddress(hSysDll, "DwmSetWindowAttribute");
    s_DwmGetWindowAttribute =  (pfnDwmGetWindowAttribute)GetProcAddress(hSysDll, "DwmGetWindowAttribute");
}
...  
...  
bool IsAeroEnabled()
{
    BOOL bAero = FALSE;
    if(s_DwmIsCompositionEnabled)
        s_DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&bAero);
    return bAero != FALSE;
}
...  
...  
HRESULT ProxyDwmSetWindowAttribute(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute)
{
    if (s_DwmSetWindowAttribute)
    {
        return s_DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, dwAttribute, pvAttribute, cbAttribute);
    }
    return E_FAIL;
}
```

Comment: One ques - will this set the NC rendering policy globally (i.e. for all other applications as well) or only for that window specific to the handle? And Shall we reset the original settings after the event (identifying the window) is over?

Comment: Also, I am drawing the rectangle in the client area only and not in NC area. I am using `CCLinetDC` for this, which certainly draws in client area only.

Comment: @Hemant Ah.. my words are misleading. Anyway, it could be the DWM related issue. You can verify it by see if problem solved when DWM composition disabled. Change Desktop Theme to the non-Aero one.

Comment: @Hemant Sorry, I missed your mention about CClientDC. DwmSetWindowAttribute change window specific attribute (top level window). Use DwmIsCompositionEnabled API for check whether or not DWM composition is enabled.

Comment: @9dan: one more thing, will this code compile/run on a XP machine?

Comment: @Hemant need Platform SDK to compile and won't run on XP if you link against DWM library. Use LoadLibrary (answer updated).

Comment: Thanks Dan, for all the time and effort u took to help me get a solution. More or less i got a clue, it lies with the rendering mechanism used by DWM.  
Its working fine if DWM composition is disabled. But thats a global setting and i don't want to go that way. _Disabling NC area rendering policy or transition effects_ just didn't work out.

Comment: yes... i finally i got to fix the issue ... i just need to touch the top level window and life is smooth :)  
As I understood it (pls correct if my perception is wrong) - DWM didn't refresh the scene unless there is some modification in the top level window and in my case i was trying to draw the border for a child window, so DWM was not doing the needful.