# Disable transparency for any given window (not for all) in Windows Vista/7

Tags: windows, winapi, transparency, aero

How do i disable transparency for any given window (not for all) in Windows Vista/7?
My goal is to take screenshot of window without background being visible through glass borders.

Comment: To Hans Passant: as i said i need to change transparency for one window not for all by disabling composition.

Comment: See [DwmSetWindowAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here are two related answers on SO: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146365/handling-wm-ncpaint-breaks-dwm-glass-rendering-on-vista-aero/1146549#1146549), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602936/delay-in-drawing-on-windows-7-os/4603045#4603045).

Comment: Unfortunately DwmSetWindowAttribute won't work. It may disable aero on specific window, but can't do the same with transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. What you can do is open another window or two (or three or four) and resize them to the same width and drag it underneath the window you want to have opaque.